# Compare to tables in a mysql-database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got two tables in a mysql-database.

table "names":

```
ID | name
100 | smith
136 | king
224 | brown
485 | miller
```

and the second table "adresses":

```
name_ID | adress  
100 | mainstreet 11
101 | hiddleburger street 33
102 | great avenue 1022
103 | panorama avenue 687
... | ...
```

In table "names" I've got 4 entries (ID 100, 136, 224, 485).
In table "adresses" I've got a few hundret entries.

Now I want to delete all the entries from adresses that have no matching names in table "names".
So I want to delete all adress-entries, that are not name_ID 100,136,224,485.

How can I do that? How can I compare those to tables?

Thank you!

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` and then `WHERE ... IS NULL`.  That will give you "*unmatched*" rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT IN and a subquery. Something like this perhaps:

```
delete from addresses where name_ID NOT IN (select ID from names);
```

performance may not be so good, but it will work.